# function with strtok rolling in the deep

Tags: c, function, ip, case, strtok

I'm currently developing a program, that can read IP with and without their mask.
I have to seperate my validate IP in 4 parts.
But when I'm executing my function it's rolling again and again.

```
void extraction_ip(char **ip,char **ip1,char **ip2,char **ip3,char **ip4){
   char *ch;
   int i = 0;
   ch = *ip;
   *ip1=strtok(ch, ".");

   while( i < 4) {
      i++;
      switch (i)
      {
      case 1:
         *ip2=strtok(NULL, ".");
         break;
      case 2:
         *ip3=strtok(NULL, ".");
         break;
      case 3:
         *ip4=strtok(NULL, ".");
         break;
      default:
         break;
      }
   }
}
```

I tried earlier with a bidimensionnal array but it was too complicated for me, I didn't find the right way to do it. 
The call of this function is:

```
extraction_ip(&ip,&ip1,&ip2,&ip3,&ip4);
```

Comment: `while (ip4 != NULL || i < 4)`. Have a think: when does that condition ever become false? That is, does `ip4` ever become `NULL`?

Comment: Why are you using pointers for this?  Can you please show how you are calling it, include how you set up the input variables.

Comment: My bad i rewrote this mistake, but when i do that out of my function, with a test programm, the good value are printed. But when i do it in a function ip2/3/4 are null

Comment: @ryyker    char *ip1;
   char *ip2;
   char *ip3;
   char *ip4;
   char *ip;
On my main

Comment: Okay, but can you show how you initialized them?  i.e., they are pointers, and will need memory.  Would  `char ip_1[5];`, work? (simplifies things a little, don't you think?)

Comment: @ryyker I'll try this. Just the fact is that this function is working when i copy paste it on a test programm but here only ip1 is not null and has the good value

Answer (score 0):

The original code does not show how pointer to pointer variables are initialized, but would certainly require dynamic memory allocation before using.  The problem description however suggests that code could be simplified by using much simpler `char ip1[4];` variable types.  Following are two approaches illustrating use of variable that do not need `calloc()` or `malloc()` to use, as well as including some constructs commonly used with `strtok()`

This first approach uses simple `char` array variables to allow your prototype to most *resemble* your original but *without* using pointers:

Note: additional error checking should be added to following examples as needed for your purposes.

```
void extration_ip(char *ip, char *ip1, char *ip2, char *ip3, char *ip4);

int main(void)
{
    const char ip[] = {"192.370.23.115"};
    char ip1[4];  //simple, none-pointer char arrays of sufficient length  
    char ip2[4];    
    char ip3[4];    
    char ip4[4];

    extration_ip(ip.ip_addr, ip1, ip2, ip3, ip4);

    return 0;
}  

void extration_ip_2(char *ip, char *ip1, char *ip2, char *ip3, char *ip4)
{
    char *tok = NULL;
    char *dup = strdup(ip);
    if(dup)
    {
        tok = strtok(dup, ".");
        if(tok)
        {
            strcpy(ip1, tok);
            tok = strtok(NULL, ".");
            if(tok)
            {
                strcpy(ip2, tok);
                tok = strtok(NULL, ".");
                if(tok)
                {
                    strcpy(ip3, tok);
                    tok = strtok(NULL, ".");
                    if(tok)
                    {
                        strcpy(ip4, tok);   
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        free(dup);//must free memory from call to strdup
    }
    return; 
}
```

This second approach is responding to your stated earlier attempt:
*I tried earlier with a bidimensionnal array but it was too complicated for me, I didn't find the right way to do it.*.  It does use a 2D array, packaged with along with `char ip_addr;` to contain the ip address string input.  This approach will simplify the argument list, and provide a single container for both input and outputs:

```
typedef struct {
    char ip[4][4];// 2D char array
    char ip_addr[20];
}IP;

void extraction_ip(IP *ip);//simplified argument list using struct

int main(void)
{
    IP ip;

    strcpy(ip.ip_addr, "192.370.23.115");//input some ip address for test
    extraction_ip(&ip);

    return 0;
}

void extraction_ip(IP *part)
{
    char *tok = NULL;
    char *dup = strdup(part->ip_addr);
    if(dup)
    {
         int i = 0;        
         tok = strtok(dup, ".");
         while(tok)//loop on array to tokenize ip_address into it components.
         {
             strcpy(part->ip[i], tok);
             tok = strtok(NULL, ".");
             i++;
         }
         free(dup);
    }    
}
```

Comment: Thx,I'll try that tomorrow.

Comment: @TagZK - There are two variations for you to look at :)